# How do I make a Password Prompt which will show a picture or text with the correct password, with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, passwords

I want to have an image or text appear, if the correct password is entered. How would I make a "GUI" or Command line that says: "Enter Password". And if you get it right, you can see the concealed image/text?

Comment: Your question is *massively* too broad. to answer this we'd need to explain how to accept user input, how to check input against a stored password (and how to store the password in the first place), and how to display the image. And then all of those get multiplied by "GUI or command line" since that is two broad categories of UI and the answers to many of the above would vary depending on which *specific* implementation of either you were asking about.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't realize that was too broad.

Comment: Should the user create a password themselves? Or do you want to store a password yourselves and then tell the user to enter it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small snippet which shows a password prompt in JS.

```js
let randomPassword = "secretpassword";

let counter = 0;
let wasGuessed = false;
// give you three trys
while(!wasGuessed && counter < 3){
  let pw = prompt("Type in a Password");
  if(pw === randomPassword){
      console.log("Here is the picture");  
      wasGuessed = true;
  }else{
    alert(`This was your ${counter+1} try`);
  }
  counter ++;
}
```